# restar dos fechas para saber edad C#

Tags: c#

Necesito restar dos fechas en C#. 
Una de ellas la obtengo mediante un método que me la devuelve en DateTime.
La segunda es la fecha actual que obtengo mediante:

```
DateTime thisDay = DateTime.Today;
```

la resta la hago de la siguiente manera:

```
TimeSpan age = thisDay - birthDay;
```

Esto me está devolviendo el número de días y además una hora (00:00:00). Quiero que me devuelva tan solo el número de años. 
Por otro lado me gustaría poder extraer de ambas fechas el día, el mes y el año por separado para poder hacer cálculos exactos de una edad...
¿Cómo lo hago?

```
//a partir de aquí está bien, solo faltaba recompilar. Por eso no funcionaba.
```

He tratado de hacer lo siguiente:

```
DateTime birthDay =this.metodoX(objeto.birthdate.Value); 
//El métodoX me devuelve un DateTime de mi Base de datos.
        int day = birthDay.Day;
        int month = birthDay.Month;
        int year = birthDay.Year;

        DateTime thisDay = DateTime.Today;

        int current_day = thisDay.Day;
        int current_month = thisDay.Month;
        int current_year = thisDay.Year;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una opción es convertir tu timespan a un nuevo DateTime y desde ahí puedes transformarlo como tú quieras:

```
DateTime thisDay = DateTime.Today;
TimeSpan age = thisDay - birthDay;
DateTime totalTime = new DateTime(age.Ticks);
```

Podrás acceder a las propiedades de `DateTime` desde `totalTime`

Comment: Editaré la pregunta para que vean lo que he hecho...

Comment: Finalmente, lo estaba haciendo bien. El problema era que no había compilado y no se habían aplicado los cambios. Errores de novato. disculpad y muchísimas gracias por las respuestas!!

Answer (score 3):

Primero, lo que respecta a obtener el año, mes y día de un [`DateTime`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.datetime?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.DateTime);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8), podes simplemente usar sus propiedades correspondientes ([`Year`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.datetime.year?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.DateTime.Year);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8), [`Month`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.datetime.month?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.DateTime.Month);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8) y [`Day`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.datetime.day?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.DateTime.Day);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8))

Ya sabiendo esto, pasemos al otro punto, para obtener la diferencia de años entre dos fechas, lo más conveniente, es convertir el [`TimeSpan`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.timespan?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.TimeSpan);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8) resultante nuevamente en un [`DateTime`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.datetime?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.DateTime);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8).

```
DateTime resultado = tuTimeSpan + new DateTime(1,1,1);
```

Luego, para conocer los años, bastaría con usar la propiedad [`Year`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.datetime.year?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.DateTime.Year);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8)

```
int añosResultantes = resultado.Year -1
```

Como verás, le resté `1` a los años, ¿porqué? Porque el calendario gregoriano comienza en el año `1`, por lo cual, si no restásemos `1` siempre tendríamos un año más en nuestro resultado.

Usé como fuente, [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127363/date-difference-in-years-using-c-sharp) de SOen

Answer (score 1):

Teniendo la cantidad de días, puedes saber los años ya que un año tiene 365,25 días:

```
DateTime thisDay = DateTime.Today;
DateTime birthDay = DateTime.MinValue;
TimeSpan age = thisDay - birthDay;
Console.WriteLine(age.TotalDays / 365.25);
```

El código anterior muestra un valor cercano a 2018<sup>1</sup>:

> ```
> 2018,33812457221
> ```

Pues han pasado 2018 años desde el año 0.

---

1. En la fecha de publicación de esta respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear un método de extension que calcule los años.

```
public static class TimeSpanExtensions
{
    public static int GetYears(this TimeSpan timespan)
    {
        return (int)(timespan.Days / 365.2425);
    }
}
```

Recupera la diferencia con la función `Subtract`.

```
DateTime fechaNacimiento = new DateTime(1980, 5, 12);
DateTime fechaActual = DateTime.Now;
var anios = fechaActual.Subtract(fechaNacimiento).GetYears();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola para obtener el año puedes probar el siguiente método

```
    public static class Operaciones
    {
        public static int GetYearsOld(DateTime birthdate)
        {
            var diff = DateTime.Now - birthdate;
            return (int)(diff.TotalDays / 365.255);
        }
    }
```

y Usarlo así:

```
int yearsOld = Operaciones.GetYearsOld(new DateTime(1990,09,28));
```

Answer (score 0):

hace unos días tuve un problema similar y aquí (en Stackoverflow) encontré la solucion que te expongo, desgraciadamente no he podido encontrar de nuevo el post para agradecer a la persona que brindó la solución pues resolví el problema exactamente como quería.

la solucion es esta:

```
public int CalculateAge(DateTime data)
    {
        DateTime dateNow = DateTime.Now;

        //obtengo la fecha en años, meses y dias
        int year= dateNow.Year - data.Year;
        int month = dateNow.Month - data.Month;
        int day = dateNow.Day - data.Day;
        
        //hago la comparación
        if (month < 0)
        {
            //devuelvo la edad en años teniendo en cuenta la diferencia de meses
            return year - 1;
        }

        else if (month == 0)
        {
            //devuelvo la edad en años teniendo en cuenta la diferencia de días
            return day <= 0 ? year : year - 1;
        }

        else
        {
            return year;
        }
    }
```

Repito, la solución la vi en otro post y me resultó de maravilla, espero que te ayude a ti también.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo solucione así

```
Tuple<int,int,int> CalculaEdad(DateTime FechaInicial, DateTime FechaFinal)
{
    var ts = FechaFinal - FechaInicial;
    DateTime dt = new DateTime(ts.Ticks).AddYears(1).AddMonths(-1).AddDays(-1);
    return new Tuple<int, int, int>(dt.Year - 2, dt.Month, dt.Day);
}
```

al final ya solo retornas con las propiedades del DateTime dt;
le añadí 1 año y le reste un mes y un día, esto para evitar errores pues no puede existir DateTime con valores 0 en año, mes o día y este se inicializa con un año, un mes y un día, al final ya solo resto 2 años a Year, compárenlo con la calculadora de Windows funciona!